# What is an acceptable render time for a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the "React Developer Tools" extension, a profiler has been added that displays the time spent on rendering. Are there any guidelines/table? For example, an acceptable render time for an average web application should be 50-300ms. Or like performance index in chrome developer tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In generally, render should take about 16 milliseconds. Any longer than that and things start feeling really janky.
I would recommend this article on performance in react. He is explaining more about profiling and performance in react. 
performance with react(with forms) : https://epicreact.dev/improve-the-performance-of-your-react-forms/

 profiling article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/profile-a-react-app-for-performance

Comment: 16 ms? Where does the source come from?

Comment: In order to achieve 60 frames per second, each frame should render in < 16milliseconds, its calculated by dividing time by frame count, so if you want 60 frames in a second then 1/60 = 0.01666, if they're consistently higher then you'll drop frames as it can't keep up with the refresh rate

Comment: I think that’s related to animation render? We are taking about rendering general React components..

Comment: Most of the sites, apps I use, whether they are created with react or not, take more than 1 second to render for sure.

Comment: @JudeGao hey, I provided the sources with links to the articles in my answer.